# Hide on Step 1 and Show on Step 2 div section Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I wanted to Hide a div section on step 1 and when click button or submitted it will display on step 2.
I tried adding a Javascript but still not working.

Order Summary should be hidden on the 1st step and on 2nd step, Order summary must be shown. `
I wanted to apply this for mobile view only.

```
 <div class="chk-box">
               <div class="chk-rgt">
                  <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/old-man.png" class="old-man hide-mob">
                  <p class="chk-rgt-txt1">Order Summary</p>
                  <div class="chk-rgt-mid">
                     <img src="<?= $image ?>" class="prod" style="max-width:280px;margin: 0 0 5px;">
                     <div class="chk-rtlbx">
                        <div class="chkrtlinbx-top">
                           <p class="chkrtlprc chkrtlprc1">Retail Price</p>
                           <p class="chkrtlprc2"><span class="strikeout">$<?= $retail_price ?></span></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="chkrtlinbx-btm position">
                           <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/rtlarrow.png" alt="" class="chkrtlarrow">
                           <p class="chkrtlprc">Offer Price</p>
                           <p class="chkrtlprc3">$<?= (int) $product_details['product_price'] ?></p>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <p class="chk-prc">Tommy Chong’s Good Vibes<br> Protocol w/ Nano CBD <?= $supply ?><span>$<?= (int) $product_details['product_price'] ?></span></p>
                     <ul class="pric-list">
                        <li>Sales Tax :</li>
                        <li>$0.00</li>
                        <li>Shipping & Handling : </li>
                        <li>FREE</li>
                        <li>Grand Total :</li>
                        <li>$<?= (int) $product_details['product_price'] ?></li>
                     </ul>
                     <div class="rght-box hide-mob">
                        <ul class="icon-sec">
                           <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon1.png"><br>GMO Free</li>
                           <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon2.png"><br>Gluten Free</li>
                           <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon3.png"><br>Made In USA</li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div id="checkout" class="chk-left">
                  <form method="post" action="ajax.php?method=downsell1" name="downsell_form1" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8" id="downsell_form1">
                     <input type="hidden" name="no_use" id="no_use" value="utf-8" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="campaigns[1][id]" value="<?php echo ($_REQUEST['product'] ? $_REQUEST['product'] : '1') ?>">
                     <input type="hidden" name="billingSameAsShipping" value="yes"/>
                     <div id="shippingInfo" style=" float:left; width:100%;">
                        <div class="chk-lft-top">
                           <p class="chk-stp1"><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/icon1.png" class="icon1"><span>Step 1 Of 2 <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/chk-grn-arw.png" class="chk-grn-arw"></span>
                              <br>Shipping Information
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-mid">
                           <div class="frmElmnts1">
                              <label>First Name *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" class="required" data-error-message="Please enter your first name!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts2">
                              <label>Last Name *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" class="required" data-error-message="Please enter your last name!" />
                           </div><div class="clearall"></div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts3">
                              <label>Address *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="shippingAddress1" placeholder="Your Address" class="required" data-error-message="Please enter your address!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts1">
                              <label>City *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="shippingCity" placeholder="Your City" class="required" data-error-message="Please enter your city!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts1" style="display: none;">
                              <label>Country :*</label>
                              <select name="shippingCountry" class="required" data-selected="US" data-error-message="Please select your country!">
                                 <option value="">Select Country</option>
                              </select>
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts2">
                              <label>State *</label>
                              <input type="text" name="shippingState" placeholder="Your State" class="required" data-error-message="Please select your state!" readonly />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts1">
                              <label>Zip Code *</label>step2Btn
                              <input type="tel" name="shippingZip" data-validate="zip" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zip Code" class="required" data-error-message="Please enter a valid zip code!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts2">
                              <label>Phone *</label>
                              <input type="tel" name="phone" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="10" placeholder="Phone" class="required" data-validate="phone" data-min-length="10" data-max-length="15" data-error-message="Please enter a valid contact number!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts3">
                              <label>Email *</label>
                              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="required" data-validate="email" data-error-message="Please enter a valid email id!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="clearall"></div>
                           <input type="image" src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/chk-btn1.png" id="shippingButton" class="chk-btn chk-btn1 step2Btn">
                           <div class="post">
                              <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/post.png" class="forDesk">
                              <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/post-mob.png" class=" forTab forMob">
                              <p>
                                 Your Order is estimated to arrive by<br class="forDesk forTab hide-mob"> 
                                 <span>
                         
                                 </span>
                              </p>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div id="billingInfo" style="display:none; float:left; width:100%;">
                        <div class="chk-lft-top">
                           <p class="chk-stp1"><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/icon2.png" class="icon1"><span>Step 2 Of 2 <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/chk-grn-arw.png" class="chk-grn-arw"></span>
                              <br>Payment Information
                           </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-mid form-mid2">
                           <div class="sameas">
                              <label>
                              <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="chkbx" id="billingAddressCheckbox">
                              Billing address same as shipping.
                              </label>
                           </div>
                           <div class="billing-info" style="display:none;">
                              <div class="frmElmnts1">
                                 <label>First Name *</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="billingFirstName" class="field-all" placeholder="Billing First Name" data-error-message="Please enter your billing first name!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts2">
                                 <label>Last Name *</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="billingLastName"  class="field-all" placeholder="Billing Last Name" data-error-message="Please enter your billing last name!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts3">
                                 <label>Address *</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="billingAddress1" class="field-all" placeholder="Billing Address" data-error-message="Please enter your billing address!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts1">
                                 <label>City *</label>
                                 <input type="text" class="field-all" name="billingCity" placeholder="Billing City" data-error-message="Please enter your billing city!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts1" style="display: none;">
                                 <label>Billing Country:*</label>
                                 <select name="billingCountry" data-selected="US" data-error-message="Please select your billing Country!">
                                    <option value="">Select Country</option>
                                 </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts2">
                                 <label>State *</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="billingState" placeholder="Billing State" data-error-message="Please enter your billing state!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts1">
                                 <label>Zip Code *</label>
                                 <input type="tel" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" maxlength="5" name="billingZip" class="field-all" placeholder="Billing Zip Code" data-error-message="Please enter a valid billing zip code!" />
                              </div>
                              <div class="clearall"></div>
                           </div>
                           <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/cards.png" class="cards">
                           <div class="clearall"></div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts1">
                              <label>Card Type</label>
                              <select name="creditCardType" id="creditCardType" class="field-all required" data-error-message="Please select valid card type!">
                                 <option value="">Card Type</option>
                                 @php 
                                    foreach($config['allowed_card_types'] as $key=>$value): 
                                    @endphp
                                    <option value="@php echo $key @endphp">@php echo ucfirst($value) @endphp</option>
                                    @php 
                                    endforeach 
                                    @endphp
                              </select>
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts2">
                              <label>Card Number</label>
                              <input type="tel" name="creditCardNumber" class="field-all required" maxlength="16" data-error-message="Please enter a valid credit card number!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts1 frmElmnts111 exp-det">
                              <div class="frmElmnts1 frmElmnts11">
                                 <label>Expiration Date</label>
                                 <select name="expmonth" class="field-all required expmonth" data-error-message="Please select a valid expiry month!">
                                 @php get_months(); @endphp
                                 </select>
                              </div>
                              <div class="frmElmnts2 frmElmnts11">
                                 <label>Expiration Year</label>
                                 <select name="expyear" class="field-all required" data-error-message="Please select a valid expiry year!">
                                @php get_years(); @endphp
                                 </select>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="frmElmnts2 frmElmnts22 cvv-holder">
                              <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:openNewWindow('page-cvv.php', 'modal');" class="cvv-pop"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                              <label>CVV</label>
                              <input type="tel" name="CVV" onkeypress="return onlyNumbers(event);" class="field-all required" data-validate="cvv" maxlength="3" data-error-message="Please enter a valid CVV code!" />
                           </div>
                           <div class="clearall"></div>
                           <div class="sameas sameas2">
                                <label>
                                  <input type="checkbox" name="cus-checkbox-group" class="chkbx2 agree-checkbox" data-error-message="You have to agree with the terms in order to proceed!">
                                  By clicking submit I agree to the <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="javascript:openNewWindow('page-terms.php', 'modal'); return false;" class="trms">terms of use</a>
                                </label>
                           </div>
                           <input type="image" src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/chk-btn.jpg" class="chk-btn">
                           <div class="clearall"></div>
                           <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/visa.png" class="visa">
                           <div class="mony-seal-sec">
                              <img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/mony-seal.png" class="mony-seal">
                              <p class="seal-txt1">Life Time <br class="forMob">Money Back Guarantee</p>
                              <p class="seal-txt2">Your purcahse of Tommy Chong's CBD is backed by our <span>Life Time Money Back Guaranteee!</span><br class="forDesk"> In case you are not satisfied with the results, we will refund your money, no hassles & no questions asked.</p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="rght-box forMob">
                              <ul class="icon-sec">
                                 <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon1.png"><br>GMO Free</li>
                                 <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon2.png"><br>Gluten Free</li>
                                 <li><img src="@php echo $path['images'] @endphp/seal-icon3.png"><br>Made In USA</li>
                              </ul>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <p id="loading-indicator" style="display:none;">Processing...</p>
                     <p id="crm-response-container" style="display:none;">CRM messages will appear here...</p>
                  </form>
               </div>
            </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    const shippingButton = document.getElementById("shippingButton");
const chkrgt = document.querySelector(".chk-rgt");

const toggleShowList = () => {
  const isHidden = chkrgt.style.display === "none";
  if (isHidden) {
    // Display hidden element
    chkrgt.style.display = "block";
    actionButton.innerHTML = "Hide List";
  } else {
    // Hide element
    chkrgt.style.display = "none";
    actionButton.innerHTML = "Show List";
  }
};

// Adding click event listener
actionButton.addEventListener("click", toggleShowList);
    </script>
```

I wanted to Hide a div section on step 1 and when click button or submitted it will display on step 2.
I tried adding a Javascript but still not working. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Order Summary should be hidden on the first step and on 2nd step, Order summary must be shown.